# To extract text values and append to a list in python

Tags: python, html

I need to extract all the values between the HTML tags and append them to a list using Python.

Raw data:

```
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">a</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">b</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
</DOC> -->
<DIV CLASS="c10">&nbsp;</DIV>
<A NAME="DOC_ID_0_1"></A><!-- Hide XML section from browser
<DOC NUMBER=2>
<DOCFULL> -->
**<<BR><DIV CLASS="c5">
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">c</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">d</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">e</P>
</DIV>
```

In the above raw data, I need to extract the text values inside < All text data>

and append them to a list. I need to do the same thing  for all similar tag combinations.

**Solution that I have tried:**

```
textpattern="\<P CLASS=\"c9\"\><SPAN CLASS=\"c2\"\>(.*)\</SPAN>"
textpatternvalues=[a.strip("*") for a in re.findall(textpattern,response,re.MULTILINE)]
textvalues = re.sub(cleanr, '', str(textpatternvalues))
print(textvalues)
```

**Solution that I have obtained:** Note: Here I am not writing the original result as data is very huge. So I have written a sample of how my result was.

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

<< Here I am getting each paragraph's text appended into a single list instead as a whole where the text between `<P class=c9> * </P><BR>` should be as below i.e. it should be in the first element. The following text should be in second element of list instead of being separated.

Expected solution:

```
['a\nb\n','c\n\d\ne']
```

I have also tried with BeautifulSoup, where I am get the same result.

Comment: Looking at your expected output, it looks like you want to extract the text inside each `<div>`, and interpret each <br> as a new line character. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `lxml` parsing capabilities and `xpath`:

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring('''<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">a</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">b</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
</DOC> -->
<DIV CLASS="c10">&nbsp;</DIV>
<A NAME="DOC_ID_0_1"></A><!-- Hide XML section from browser
<DOC NUMBER=2>
<DOCFULL> -->
**<<BR><DIV CLASS="c5">
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">c</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">d</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">e</P>
</DIV>''')

['\n'.join(text for text in div.xpath('.//p//text()')) for div in tree.xpath('//div') if div.getchildren()]
```

Will output:

```
['a\nb\nc\nd\ne', 'a\nb', 'c\nd\ne']
```

(first one is a div added by lxml to have a single toplevel tag, it should not happen with your full input)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1. How can i split the list into two separate lines based on ''? 2. Why there is blank in between two list of element?

Comment: 1. please precise the question
2. there is a blank because you have an empty div in your html code. I edited the code to remove it

Comment: 1. My question is how can i split a list into two separate list based on the blank value. I mean to say [a\nb],['c\d\e] into separate list

Comment: Can you please help me to solve the above problem where i need to split the list into two based on '' spearator

Comment: I don't understand what you need. You want `['a\nb', 'c\nd\ne']` split into 2 lists of 1 single element like `[['a\nb'], ['c\nd\ne']]` ? Replace the last line by `[['\n'.join(text for text in div.xpath('.//p//text()'))] for div in tree.xpath('//div') if div.getchildren()]` then

Comment: I need value based on class name and not only tag name as my data contains few more tags with same tag name <P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">1. The first digit on your credit card account number is a signal to those in the know. What does it indicate?</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">A. How high your credit limit is.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">B. What year the card was issued.</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c7">What Do You Know About Your Credit Card?</SPAN></P>

Comment: Here basically i want to extract only the text from the nested list.[[''], [''], ["Johnson & Johnson posts third-quarter profit of $4.27 billion,  with lower-priced biosimilar Inflectra (M)"], [''], [''],  [''], ["After the Treasury Department announced new rules in  reform with specific anti-inversion and earnings stripping provisions,'' he said."], [''], [''], ['']] The outer list should remain same. output should look.["Johnson & Johnson posts third-quarter profit of $4.27 billion,  with lower-priced biosimilar Inflectra (M)",After the Treasury Department announced provisions,'' he said."]